# d3 geojson only displaying first feature

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I am trying to display the contents of a geojson file in an svg element.

For some reason, my code only renders the first feature.

When I inspect the svg element, I can see that it has created multiple paths for each feature, but each feature is identical.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(geojson.features)
                .enter()
                .select(target)
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("class", classAttr)
```

I'm using d3 v5:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You question, as asked, is not sufficient to provide any answers.  You need to provide a reproducible example.  Heck, even sharing your geojson file might get a little help.